# Close a running program with AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I can't any specific documentation of if you can or cannot, but I'm guessing there's a reason why. I'm looking to close down an application via AIR. (e.g. Close Photoshop with the press of a button inside of an air application).

As of right now AIR cannot see current system processes? I think!? So i'm guessing I can't but if anyone has found a recourse or has any information that would be very helpful. One way or another.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do it directly from AIR but it could be done by using an [ANE](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html). However, you'd probably have to write the ANE yourself - i doubt anyone has created exactly what you need.

Comment: Yikes! Sounds like more fun things to learn. This should be interesting. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Would depend on the OS, but under OSX/Linux you could use something like **ps** to search the running processes and kill the one you required by executing a script through the NativeProcess call? Not really sure on the Windows equivalent though I'm sure there's some Powershell stuff you could do. Something like this combined with a kill script?

```
ps aux | grep Adobe\ Photoshop
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html